# Searching for a a particular element ID containing a parcel string using Xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm not proficient in Xpath and I encounter some difficulties when tried to retrieve all the elements in which the ID contains a string that starts with "adfr_ed_frame". But by some reason it does not retrieve any element on the page, except if I'm executing it inside the node where is the element with the specific ID. But I need to run the code in any page and then search for that specific ID and retrieve the element.
I'm guessing that the "descendant" axis just applies to the context node, but if this is the case I have no idea how to wide up the search in the all document.
My example code:

```
    Function get_elements(xpath, descendant){
    let results = [];
    let query = document.evaluate(xpath, descendant || document, 
    null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (let i=0, length=query.snapshotLength; i<length; ++i){
    if (query.snapshotItem(i).id != ""){
    results.push(query.snapshotItem(i));
    }
    }
    return results;
    }
    results = (get_elements("//*[contains(@id, 'adfr_ed_frame')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

to use an attribute in an xpath string use the sing `@` before to set that it's an attribute name

```
//*[contains(@id, 'adfr_ed_frame')]
```

Comment: Yes sorry splash58 I have it, just made some mistake passing to code to here. Going to edit it now Thank you for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[@id[contains(./text(), 'adfr_ed_frame')]]
```

Which reads as:

All elements having attribute `id` whose text content contains `adfr_ed_frame`.

Comment: I understand what You did, however the main problem here is that I still do not get any results in the array, because if I'm executing this on the "top" of the page it will not return any result. Probably because what I refer before: "descendant" axis just applies to the context node. And I do not know in which node I need to execute this in each random page. That is why I needed a solution to search in all page, without identifying a specific node.

Comment: `//` should select all such elements, given that you evaluate it on the root node of the document. Could you post an example of the "top" of the page xml?

Comment: You mean the source code of the page or just the code of a particular node ?

Comment: I mean the xml that produces no results for this xpath.